# How do I make a token untransferable?

Tags: solidity, tokens, smart-contract-wallets

How Do I make a token untransferable by the wallet owner and only transferable by the token smart contract

Comment: Have you put any thoughts into how this could be implemented?

Comment: I'm actually very new to Ethereum and solidity

Comment: Then you might want to start with a development tutorial like the [Foundry Book](https://book.getfoundry.sh/). Also consider checking out the other tutorials mentioned [here](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1507377391965986818).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all erc20 tokens are technically transfered by the smart contract, in order to transfer, you call the token smart contract to execute the transfer.

If what you mean is you don't want the token owner to be able to transfer the token, and instead want it to be transfered on some specific conditions, or another parties input to the contract, you need to disable the transfer and transferFrom functions on the erc20 smart contract.

A good example of this from the wild is Aave Debt tokens. Debt should not be able to be given away to others without their consent, so they have made the transfer and transferFrom functions revert on call.
https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/protocol/tokenization/base/DebtTokenBase.sol

Generally though I think this is only something you want to do in pretty specific situations, and you should give some deep thought to if this is really the best solution for your problem. Most applications that use erc20 tokens will expect them to be transferable, and one of the core attributes of owning something is usually having control of giving it to someone or something.

What are you trying to accomplish specifically with your design?

Answer (score 0):

Heyy I agree with Bruce Darcy .But if you really want to  make it non transferable

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

If you check the code above you can see when you are calling transfer or transferFrom function it is calling another function within the smart contract called _transfer().

You can disable the transfer and transferFrom function and directly call the _transfer(). You can remove the internal keyword and add a [modifier](https://solidity-by-example.org/function-modifier/) to _transfer().

Hope this is what you are looking for